# Working with archives through the Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm interested in the question of working with archives through the Google Drive API. I am new and in my project I use Electron, can I **send the archive to the cloud and unzip it there**? What do I need for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's an [answer on Quora about doing this on Google Collab](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-extract-a-zip-file-inside-Google-Drive/answer/Vivek-Amilkanthawar-1) but I don't know if that's scriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the Google Drive API doesn't have an endpoint for this. However, you can host [Drive Zip Extractor](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/drive-zipextractor) on something like a web server, and upload you zipped files into that, which it will unzip and put into your drive.